# Ressource doesn't exist Discord API PATCH method FiveM

Tags: lua, discord, fivem

I'm currently facing an issue when trying to interact with the Discord API using a FiveM server written in Lua.

Here is the piece of code I believe to be causing the issue:

```
function DiscordRequest(method, endpoint, jsondata, reason)
    local data = nil
    PerformHttpRequest("https://discord.com/api/"..endpoint, function(errorCode, resultData, resultHeaders)
        data = {data=resultData, code=errorCode, headers=resultHeaders}
    end, method, #jsondata > 0 and jsondata or "", {["Content-Type"] = "application/json", ["Authorization"] = FormattedToken, ['X-Audit-Log-Reason'] = reason})

    while data == nil do
        Citizen.Wait(0)
    end

    return data
end
```

here is the token formatting:

```
local FormattedToken = "Bot " .. 'my_bot_token'
```

And my functions return error : The ressource at the location specified doesn't exist

```
function AddPermissions(userId, categoryId, isboss, reason)
    local discordId = nil
    for _, id in ipairs(GetPlayerIdentifiers(userId)) do
        if string.match(id, 'discord:') then
            discordId = string.gsub(id, 'discord:', '')
            break
        end
    end
    
    local playerPerms = 0x400 | 0x100000 | 0x200000
    if isboss then
        playerPerms = playerPerms | 0x10000000 | 0x10 | 0x800 | 0x10000 | 0x400000 | 0x1000000
    end
        
    if discordId then
        local endpoint = ("guilds/%s/channels"):format(Config.Guild_ID)
        local channels = DiscordRequest("GET", endpoint, {})
        
        if channels.code == 200 then
            local data = json.decode(channels.data)
            for _, channel in ipairs(data) do
                if channel.parent_id == categoryId then
                    local hasPermission = false
                    local permissions = channel.permission_overwrites

                    for _, permission in ipairs(permissions) do
                        if permission.id == discordId then
                            hasPermission = true
                            permission.allow = playerPerms
                            break
                        end
                    end

                    if not hasPermission then
                        table.insert(permissions, {
                            id = discordId,
                            type = 1,
                            allow = playerPerms 
                        })
                    end

                    local post = DiscordRequest("PATCH", endpoint.."/"..channel.id, json.encode({permission_overwrites = permissions}), reason)
                    if post.code ~= 200 then
                        print("AddPermissions : " .. error_codes_defined[post.code])
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

function RemovePermissions(userId, categoryId, reason)
    local discordId = nil
    for _, id in ipairs(GetPlayerIdentifiers(userId)) do
        if string.match(id, 'discord:') then
            discordId = string.gsub(id, 'discord:', '')
            break
        end
    end

    if discordId then
        local endpoint = ("guilds/%s/channels"):format(Config.Guild_ID)
        local channels = DiscordRequest("GET", endpoint, {})

        if channels.code == 200 then
            local data = json.decode(channels.data)
            for _, channel in ipairs(data) do
                if channel.parent_id == categoryId then
                    local permissionIndex = nil
                    local permission_overwrites = channel.permission_overwrites

                    for index, permission in ipairs(permission_overwrites) do
                        if permission.id == discordId then
                            permissionIndex = index
                            break
                        end
                    end

                    if permissionIndex then
                        table.remove(permission_overwrites, permissionIndex)
                        local post = DiscordRequest("PATCH", endpoint.."/"..channel.id, json.encode({permission_overwrites = permission_overwrites}), reason)
                        if post.code ~= 200 then
                            print("RemovePermissions : " .. error_codes_defined[post.code])
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I don't get any other errors, all the variables are good when retrieving the data the salons its salon id its found correctly according to the data sent, it's only the sending that is the problem and I can't understand why

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found why is 404, for edit channels details is not :
`https://discord.com/api/guilds/{GUILD_ID}/channels/{CHANNEL_ID}/permissions/{USER_ID}`

But directly :
`https://discord.com/api/channels/{CHANNEL_ID}/permissions/{USER_ID}`

Solved